# execute immediate using cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've number of tables that i want to drop some columns and add some another columns again. (oracle database)

All of tables are empty.

does it work??

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR cursor_name
    IS
        SELECT TABLE_NAME
          FROM SYS.ALL_TABLES
         WHERE OWNER = 'username';

    TN            NVARCHAR2 (30);
    TABLE_COUNT   NUMBER (3);

    TCDROP        NVARCHAR2 (1000);

    TCADD         NVARCHAR2 (1000);
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT (1)
      INTO TABLE_COUNT
      FROM SYS.ALL_TABLES
     WHERE OWNER = 'username';

    OPEN cursor_name;

    FOR i IN 1 .. TABLE_COUNT
    LOOP
        FETCH cursor_name INTO TN;

        TCDROP := 'ALTER TABLE ' || TN || ' DROP (*columns list*);';

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE TCDROP;

        TCADD :=
            'ALTER TABLE ' || TN || ' ADD (*columns and datatype list*);';

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE TCADD;

        EXIT WHEN cursor_name%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cursor_name;
END;
/
```

---

Comment: `does it work??` Try it, you will know...

Comment: First comment the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` part in your code and add a `dbms_ouput.put_line(tcdrop)` above to see if the syntax of final sql is correct. Then run it. Or better spool it into a .sql file instead of executing it in loop and run that sql file at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will certainly work. I'd recommend to put in the owner/schema of the tables, though. Besides, it is unusual or unsafe to query the number of tables and the loop through the list. I'd put it in a simple for loop:

```
DECLARE
  stmt VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  FOR t IN (SELECT table_name FROM all_tables WHERE owner='XYZ') LOOP
    stmt := 'ALTER TABLE '||owner||'.'||table_name||' DROP (*columns list*);';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(stmt);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (stmt);

    stmt:= 'ALTER TABLE '||owner||'.'||table_name||' ADD (*columns and datatype list*);';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(stmt);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (stmt);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```